# Solr: Invalid Date String:'1996'

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr. I have indexed some data in my solr(5.1.1). My data has fields like contract_year whose value are like:

```
contract year: 1996
contract year: 2000
```

The field type of contract year is "int". I want to change the field type to "date" or "tdate" with just year . For that, I have edited my **schema.xml** and changed the field type of contract year from **"int"** to **"date"**. After doing this and reindexing my data, I got this error:

```
Invalid Date String:'1996'
```

What should I do to change the field type to "date" and get the same result like

```
contract year: 1996
```

without changing the format of date. I want to get only the year(yyyy) from the date.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nupur, the only format that Solr `date` field support is of the format like this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`.So you will have to convert your date in a format like this to be accepted by Apache Solr .

Comment: How should I convert a "yyyy" format to  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" ?

Comment: See if you're only passing a year , then pass it in a normal field rather than a date field . And yes, it almost  makes no sense to convert a year value in full fledged date format . Just don't use a date field use like text_general field for storing it just as a string . But if you want to filter on year ranges ,then you may have to re-think !

Comment: Please use a int field and not a text_general or strfield - that way range queries will work as they should without any surprises suddenly showing themselves :-)

Comment: It **is** possible to parse number as just a date by reusing date parser component from the schemaless configuration and configuring update request processor chain to include that parser with instructions to look at specific field only (no automatic field creation). But I don't remember if schemaless is already available in Solr 5.1.